# How count the same items in list from database

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have table cart where I have column names:

```
cart_id,
product_id,
quantity,
user_id
```

Example:

```
<Record cart_id=26 product_id=2 quantity=Decimal('1000.00') user_id=582042554>
```

It's request on Python so maybe it can be done with Python, not with SQL and I need count how much row with the `same product_id` and `quantity` for user

It's for cart so that I can write amount of the same product

Example:

```
2 times product_id=2 with quantity=1000 
3 times product_id=4 with quantity=500
```

Comment: `SELECT count(*) FROM cart WHERE user_id=<some_user_id> GROUP BY product_id, quantity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from my understanding you want to count how many times "key" X is in a table present and return that amount ?

something like this should return your data:
(records needs to be your table and import defaultdict from collections)

```
def count_product_quantity_for_user(records, user_id):
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for record in records:
        if record['user_id'] == user_id:
            key = (record['product_id'], record['quantity'])
            counts[key] += 1
    return counts

user_id = 582042554 
counts = count_product_quantity_for_user(records, user_id)


for (product_id, quantity), count in counts.items():
    print(f"{count} times product_id={product_id} with quantity={quantity}")
```